# Combining csv files that have time series data

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'm very new to R/RStudio and I'm a bit stuck on how to combine multiple CSV based on the data that I have.

I have 50 csv files - one per subject and the file names are 'subject_1' through to 'subject_50'. Each file has two columns - time and stride_interval. Time refers to when the subject's heel strikes the walkway and the stride interval is the time between one heel strike to the next.

[image]

[image]

The data file for subject 1 has two columns time and stride_interval with around 450 rows.
Subject 2 is in its own csv file and has two columns with time and stride_interval for approximately 450 rows.

Subjects 3 to subject 50 have the same structure
and so on for about 450 rows

Some of the subjects are healthy young subjects, some are PD patients, and some are healthy aged subjects.

I've worked out how to read all the files into R.
I need to calculate things like mean and SD of the stride_int for the different groups.
I've been trying to combine my data into one tibble/data frame but because I effectively just have two columns that have the same names for each file and that they are time series data, I'm not sure if I should be doing this or not.

```
list_of_files <- list.files(path = "\path for files",
                        recursive = TRUE,
                        pattern = "\\.csv$",
                        full.names = TRUE 

df <- readr::read_csv(list_of_files, id = "file_name")
```

I get the following message in the console

```
Rows: 24148 Columns: 3                                                                                         
── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Delimiter: ","
dbl (2): time, stride_int

ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
```

I'm not sure what this means.

Also, the df is made up of Rows: 24148 Columns: 3, with column 1 showing the file name (I can track the subject but I would like for it to just say 'subject_1'. Subject 1 is in the first ~450 rows, then Subject_11 for a similar number of rows, then subject_12 until it gets to subject_2, then subject_21 etc.

I assume it isn't necessary to reorder this?

Should I even be merging the data in this way and instead use loops to run through each csv file and then create a new df with subject, mean, SD etc for each column?

Comment: I'm not really understanding the problem. The message you are getting is just informing you what was imported and letting you know of commands you can use to get more information. There is no limit to the amount of data you can import, at least up to what your machine can handle. I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: As long as you have a third variable that acts as an id of the subject, you're good to go with your analysis.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should be merging the data in this way into one dataframe as when I've been looking into this by using online examples/books etc it seems that each variable should have its own column, each observation should have its own row and each each value must have its own cell. But I'm not sure if this is right for the type of timeseries data that I have, or if I should just maybe appreciate that the standard way of looking at tables in click and point programs isn't how to look at data in R.

Comment: Yes you should be doing it this way.

Comment: Great thanks for the reassurance!

Comment: Your current format is probably optimal for further analysis, though you might want to add a column like `df$Subject_ID <- rep(1:length(unique(df$file_name)), rle(df$file_name)$lengths)` so the filenames are also expressed as simple numbers.

Comment: As for the last part of your question, you could do something like `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(Subject_ID) %>% summarize(mean = mean(stride_int), sd = SD(stride_int))` to get stats by subject. Or `library(ggplot2); df %>% ggplot(aes(time, stride_int, group = ID)) + geom_line()` to get a spaghetti plot of all the observations.

Comment: That's really helpful thankyou @JonSpring. I was trying the str_extract function but it wasn't working. As a further question, I have my demongraphic details in a different CSV file but I'm unsure as to how to combine this with my data frame because the columns are a different length. My searches online don't seem to be getting me anywhere but it might be because I'm not using the right search terms

Comment: A join is the typical way to combine two data sources that have one or more key columns in common: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html?q=join#mutating-joins.   If you know Excel, it's like VLOOKUP, but much faster.